# Not able to find zfs pool source directories

Tags: zfs, mount, zfsonlinux, zfs-fuse

I am not able to understand where zpool directories are kept on my machine?

`zfs list`

shows this output

```
NAME                                                                              USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
default                                                                           294M  17.0G    19K  none
default/containers                                                               3.76M  17.0G    19K  none
default/containers/a1                                                            3.74M  17.0G  3.74M  /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/a1
default/custom                                                                     19K  17.0G    19K  none
default/deleted                                                                    19K  17.0G    19K  none
default/images                                                                    290M  17.0G    19K  none
default/images/347f49fcb4ceada500d1bc53e0146b48b4e39074ef5895b184902d333120d5ed   290M  17.0G   290M  none
default/snapshots                                                                  19K  17.0G    19K  none
```

But when I try to search for `default/deleted`, I can't find it on my machine; I can't find any of the above.

I can see the mount point i.e. where this zfs is mounted

```
default/containers/a1 /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/a1 zfs rw,relatime,xattr,noacl 0 0
```

But I can't find the source of the mount point i.e. `default/containers/a1`

Can anyone please help? My question is i can't understand where the source of the mount point is. Where is `default/containers/a1`? Note: `default` is the name of my zfs pool.
Or in other words, I want to see where zfs pool is kept on my machine.

I can create/delete/update files by accessing the mount point of zfs; but what if i want to do it at the source itself i.e.  `default/containers/a1` instead of doing it at

```
/var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/a1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `default/containers/a1` is the source and you can only access the files via the mountpoint. ZFS stores data directly on your disks and does not use any folder or mountpoint in your filesystem tree.

If you want to see the disks that are used by your zpool `default`, use the command as follows to get the details.

```
zpool list -v default
```

All *folders* beneath `default` are ZFS filesystems which are managed by ZFS and must also be mounted to access the files that a ZFS filesystem holds.